# TimePicker to set Alarm does not work , any alternative fix ?

Tags: java, android

The objective is to set an Alarm when a time is picked from the TimePicker and an ImageButton for confirmation is pressed. However, when the button is pressed to set the Alarm, nothing happens!

The Java code for the Activity is :

```
public class Time_Date extends FragmentActivity {

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private TimePicker alarmPicker;
AlarmManager alarmManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_time__date);
    alarmPicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.time);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);



}



public void fireAlarm (View view)
{
    ImageButton alarmPower = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.setAlarm);
    alarmPower.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 
alarmPicker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 
alarmPicker.getCurrentMinute());
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Time_Date.this, 
AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Time_Date.this, 
0, myIntent, 0);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, 
calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
    });


}
```

And the XML layout code is :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
tools:context="zyia.alarm.zyia.zyia.Time_Date">
<ImageView
    android:background="@drawable/top_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



<ImageButton
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/setAlarm"
    android:onClick="fireAlarm"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

The code for Broadcast Receiver is :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {



    //this will sound the alarm tone
    //this will sound the alarm once, if you wish to
    //raise alarm in loop continuously then use MediaPlayer and 
setLooping(true)
    Uri alarmUri = 
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null) {
        alarmUri = 
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();

    //this will send a notification message
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            AlarmService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}
```

and the code of the Service used is :

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {
private NotificationManager alarmNotificationManager;

public AlarmService() {
    super("AlarmService");
}

@Override
public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    sendNotification("Wake Up! Wake Up!");
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    Log.d("AlarmService", "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
    alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, Time_Date.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder alamNotificationBuilder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(

this).setContentTitle("Alarm").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);


    alamNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    alarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alamNotificationBuilder.build());
    Log.d("AlarmService", "Notification sent.");
}
}
```

I ve tried it for almost a day finding the bug! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things pop out as potential issues:

1. Use `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` when you set your alarm, otherwise the device will not wake up from a sleep state to trigger your alarm
2. Make sure that you adjust the `Calendar` object appropriately if the time selected is *before* the current time of day.  When you call `Calendar.getInstance()` you are getting a `Calendar` object which is set to the current TOD for the Locale and TimeZone of the device.  If you selected a time in your picker which is before current TOD, then alarm won't trigger because it will have already passed for today.

One other thing you'll need to watch out for: starting with KitKat, alarms are inexact by default.  So if you need the alarm to go off at the *exact* time you are specifying, you'll need to use the method `AlarmManager.setExact()` for KK or later devices.

Comment: First thing is okay , but how do I adjust the calendar object appropriately ?

Comment: You'll have to look and see if the picker's time is before the current TOD.  If it is, you'll need to add a day to the `Calendar` object before you set the alarm (making the alarm go off at the selected time tomorrow.)